# how to make a matrix in a for loop based on these data

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I need some help for my R project. I want to make a matrix based on the average Relative Cleavage Intensity (RCI). This is my raw data(mydata = 632 obs. Of 3 variables):

```
    R.Int amino1 amino2
1      14      W      I
2       0      K      E
3      79      Q      I
4      80      Q      I
5     100      K      V
6     100      K      V
7     100      K      P
8      24      K      P
9     100      K      I
10    100      K      I  
11    100      K      I
12    100      K      I
13    100      K      I
14    100      K      E
15      4      H      E
16      0      H      E
17      0      F      Y
18      0      F      Y
19      2      E      Q
20      2      E      Q
```

I have managed so far to calculate the average RCI for all possible amino acid combinations by doing this code:

```
for (i in x)  {
  for (j in x) { 
   sub <- subset(mydata, mydata$amino1==LETTERS[i] & mydata$amino2==LETTERS[j])
   g <- group_by(sub, amino1) %>% summarize(m = mean(R.Int))
   h <- group_by(sub, amino2) %>% summarize(m = mean(R.Int))
   c <- cbind(g,h)
   d <- subset(c, select = -4)
   neworder <- d[, c(1,3,2)]
   n <- setnames(neworder, "m", "R.Int")
   if (nrow(sub) > 0)

   print(n)
 }
}
```

The above code gives this output:

```
  amino1 amino2 R.Int
1      A      L    25
  amino1 amino2 R.Int
1      A      E    41
  amino1 amino2 R.Int
1      A      R  1.25
  amino1 amino2 R.Int
1      A      K    80
  amino1 amino2 R.Int
1      A      S   4.1
  amino1 amino2 R.Int
1      G      G    12
  amino1 amino2 R.Int
1      G      L     7
  amino1 amino2 R.Int
1      G      W     2
amino1 amino2 R.Int
1      G      Y     0
amino1 amino2 R.Int
1      G      D   0.4
```

My question is: how do I build a matrix on that?  I want the matrix to look like this with the average RCI values at each possible amino acid combination:

```
   A  G  I  L  P  V  F  W  Y  D  Q  E  R  H  K  S  T  C  M  N
N NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
M NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
c NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
T NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
S NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
K NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
H NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
R NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
E NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
Q NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
D NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
Y NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
W NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
F NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
V NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
P NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
L NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
I NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
G NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
A NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

I really hope you can help me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you can accomplish this:

```
# construct example data frame
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(R.int=sample(1:100, 25, replace=T), amino1=sample(letters[1:5], 25, replace=T), amino2=sample(letters[1:5], 25, replace=T), stringsAsFactors=F)

# make sure that amino1 and amino2 are character variables (not factors)
df$amino1 <- as.character(df$amino1)
df$amino2 <- as.character(df$amino2)

# calculate mean for each amino acid combination
dfAgg <- aggregate(cbind("R.Int"=R.Int)~amino1 + amino2, data=df, FUN=mean)

# construct matrix for storage, give it row and column names of amino acids
myMat <- matrix(0, nrow=length(unique(dfAgg$amino1)), ncol=length(unique(dfAgg$amino2)))
rownames(myMat) <- unique(dfAgg$amino1)
colnames(myMat) <- unique(dfAgg$amino2)

# fill in the values
myMat[cbind(dfAgg$amino1, dfAgg$amino2)] <- dfAgg$R.Int
```

Note that your amino acid variables must be of type character (ie, not factors) for this method to work. The final line uses the combinations of the names of the amino acids as they appear in the dfAgg data.frame as indices to fill in the final matrix.

Comment: Hey Imo, thanks for the quick answer. However, I still have problems getting it done the right way. I have converted the amino variables to "characters", but when I get to the final line (#fill in the values) it gives me: Error in myMat[cbind(dfAgg$amino1, dfAgg$amino2)] <- dfAgg$R.int : replacement has length zero

Comment: two columns and a lot of rows, but no characters

Comment: it is not the case, unfortunately.

Comment: it is too large, even with < 50 rows. I post it as an answer to my own question

Comment: I posted the non-modified version of the raw data. With your edited version I still get the error. Maybe I am missing something? how should the first line (# construct example data frame) look like in my case ? I am sorry if I take too much of your time

Comment: I used your coding, but at the end the code: `myMat[cbind(dfAgg$amino1, dfAgg$amino2)] <- dfAgg$R.int` gives the error. So, do you get a proper matrix?

Comment: `str(myMat)` gives the output:  num [1:19, 1:20] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:19] "D" "E" "Q" "Y" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:20] "A" "C" "D" "E" ...

Comment: and the error is actually replaced with a new one: Error in myMat[cbind(dfAgg$amino1, dfAgg$amino2)] <- dfAgg$R.int : 
  subscript out of bounds

Comment: typeof(myMat$amino1) gives: Error in myMat$amino1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors     dim(dfAgg) gives: 131 x 3, so that one is correct

Comment: `class(myMat)` gives: "matrix" and `dim(myMat)` gives: 19 and 20

Comment: `str(mydata)` gives: 'data.frame': 632 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ R.Int : int  14 0 79 80 100 100 100 24 100 100 ...
 $ amino1: Factor w/ 20 levels "","A","C","D",..: 19 10 14 14 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
 $ amino2: Factor w/ 21 levels "","A","C","D",..: 9 5 9 9 19 19 14 14 9 9 ...

Comment: `str(mydata)`
'data.frame': 632 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ R.Int : int  14 0 79 80 100 100 100 24 100 100 ...
 $ amino1: chr  "W" "K" "Q" "Q" ...
 $ amino2: chr  "I" "E" "I" "I" ...

Comment: OK. Now does running the code starting with `dfAgg <- ...` in the answer work?

Comment: this error: Error in myMat[cbind(dfAgg$amino1, dfAgg$amino2)] <- dfAgg$R.int : 
  replacement has length zero

Comment: `dim(myMat)`: 19 and 20          `dim(cbind(dfAgg$amino1, dfAgg$amino2))`: 131 and 2      `length(dfAgg$R.int)`: 0

Comment: Aha. We found the culprit for this error anyway. I'll edit the `aggregate` function.

Comment: don't think you have to rework the `aggregate`. I just noticed that code you were running had dfAgg$R.`i`nt instead of dfAgg$R.`I`nt. When i run the code and type myMat I get a matrix! but it looks kinda ugly? its like divided in sections?

Comment: Stupid typos. Good catch. The output gets organized according to how dfAgg is organized. If I remember right, there are quite a few amino combos with zero observations, so the matrix will be somewhat sparse. Maybe the pattern of the sparseness or where the pairs are bunched up will turn out to be interesting. Glad we got this part sorted out.

Comment: nvm the last I wrote. just had to make the window bigger in R. thank you so much Imo! :D